# How to change the price in quote while adding product to cart?

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, price, custom

I want to apply a custom price for the current order. I read that I should use **sales_quote_add_item**, But its looks like I am doing something wrong. I found some tutorials for magento1 but not for Magento 2. So please let me know what I am doing wrong.

**app/code/Myvendor/HelloMagento/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_quote_add_item">
        <observer name="change_hello_magento_display" instance="Myvendor\Addtocart\Observer\Change" />
    </event>
 </config>
```

**app/code/Myvendor/HelloMagento/Observer/Change.php**

```
<?php
namespace Myvendor\Addtocart\Observer;

class Change implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
        $new_price = 987;
        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);
        $quote_item->save();
    }
}
```

Let me know please what I am doing wrong. I want to achieve the same thing for Magento 2 given on below link for magento1.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721583/changing-the-price-in-quote-while-adding-product-to-cart-magento

Comment: hi @rahul whether u would like to add in frontend?

Comment: whether you would like to change the price after add to cart please confirm thanks

Comment: hi @rahul i have used checkout_cart_product_add_after event please try and get back with your comments thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

**Step-1:** Create an **events.xml** in the following below path

> **Note:** Here i am considering the module called ***Ewall_Pricecalculations***
>
> app/code/Ewall/Pricecalculations/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
<observer name="Ewall_Pricecalculations_Addtocart" instance="Ewall\Pricecalculations\Observer\PricecalculationsAfterAddtoCart" />
</event>
</config>
```

**Step-2:** Next Create a file in the name of **PricecalculationsAfterAddtoCart.php** keep the below code as shown below.

```
<?php
namespace Ewall\Pricecalculations\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
 
class PricecalculationsAfterAddtoCart implements ObserverInterface
{
     
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
{
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/stackexchange.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            /* Code here */
            $quote_item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
            $price = 400; //set your price here
            $quote_item->setCustomPrice($price);
            $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
            $quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);

            $logger->info("success !!!!");
            
    }
}
```

> **Step 3:** please use **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

clear cache and page_cache and check the same in the frontend.

Comment: `checkout_cart_product_add_after` this event is not working in case of admin order. Is there any other event to handle this scenario?

Comment: @RanjitShinde the above event is working at front end after add to cart.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa, can we set custom taxamount for the quote item using this event?

Comment: i am note sure @jafarpinjar i will check and getback to you.

Comment: @NagarajuKasa, okay thank you, here is my question, you can update if found anything please,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart/274612

Comment: trick here is `$quote_item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
`. This set your value in quote_item table.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, and posted answer is valid for sure

Just wanted to point that the mentioned event (**sales_quote_add_item**) in question is available in Magento2, and it works fine for the asked customization with very few code

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    // your logic to get $yourPrice
    $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($yourPrice);
}
```

Note that you shouldn't `save()` QuoteItem object